# Как создать список CipherList?

Tags: delphi, ssl

В моей программе есть idHTTP с TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL и idHTTPServer с IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL. Настройки такие:

```
  ...SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'root.pem';
  ...SSLOptions.CertFile := 'cert.pem';
  ...SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'key.pem';
  ...SSLOptions.DHParamsFile := 'dhparam.pem';
  ...SSLOptions.SSLVersions := _GetSSLVersions;
  ...SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer; // и sslmClient

function _GetSSLVersions(): TIdSSLVersions;
var
  I: TIdSSLVersion;
begin
  Result := [];
  for I := Low(TIdSSLVersion) to High(TIdSSLVersion) do
  begin
    Include(Result, I);
  end;
end;
```

Вылетают такие ошибки:

> EIdOSSLAcceptError : Error accepting connection with SSL. EOF was
>   observed that violates the protocol
>
> EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError : Error accepting connection with SSL.
>   error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
>
> EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError : Error accepting connection with SSL.
>   error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate
>   unknown
>
> EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError : error:1409E10F:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_write_bytes:bad length

Чему должно быть равно .SSLOptions.CipherListдля серыера и для клиента?

Comment: Вот так: `SSLOptions.CipherList := 'ALL'`, но почему вы решили что проблема именно в этом?

Comment: @zed где то читал что сервер с клиентом не могут договориться о способе обмена ключами, я не уверен что поможет но хочу попробовать. Вы считаете что проблема в другом?